# wp8 How to disable scrolling in Panorama control

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am making an app based on Panorama control. Here my XAML below:

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
...

<phone:Panorama x:Name="MyPanorama">
     <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="FirstItem">
               ...
     </phone:PanoramaItem>
     <phone:PanoramaItem x:Name="SecondItem">
               ...
     </phone:PanoramaItem>
</phone:Panorama>
```

I want to disable scrolling between FirstItem and SecondItem, and later to enable this feature. It does not matter how to do it (by xaml or code behind), but Panorama control is required to use. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm probably late on respond to this, but the solution should be the property IsHitTestVisible.

Using this property on the panorama control, you can disable your control whenever you want to.

```
//Disable panorama scrolling
MyPanorama.IsHitTestVisible = false;

//Enable panorama scrolling
MyPanorama.IsHitTestVisible = true;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have a ListBox on my first PanoramaItem and I want to scroll it down while 'IsHitTestVisible = false' prevent Panorama from touch events. After days of 'googling' I come to conclusion that there is no way to achieve this!